# UITableView setContentOffSet is causing unwanted scrolling to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I am simulating a pull to refresh when my view loads which fetches data from an api.

```
[refreshControl beginRefreshing];
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, -refreshControl.frame.size.height);
[tableView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

when the data comes back it stops the refresh control, reloads the tableview and

```
 [refreshControl endRefreshing];   
 [_postsTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

If am at the top of the tableview fine, but if am in the middle or at the bottom it scrolls to the top undesirably.

Comment: Pull to refresh will adjust automatic no need to setContentOffset for that. Use SVPullToRefresh to improve your experience with pull to refresh

Comment: "reloads the tableview " how ?

Comment: you can use this [tableview reload] or you can add more values that are loaded from server by pulling to table by inserting rows at particulars indexpaths. This will give good animation effect. And If you have fix that only 10 row will be display in tableview at any time then use [tableview reload]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can just wrap that to avoid the undesired behavior:

```
if (_postsTableView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
    [_postsTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: fellows like you keep the world spinning man. awesome! works perfect!

Comment: sorry i dont have enough rep points yet to upvote this. :( but really appreciate it